# Loading an assembly from a dll's Byte array

Tags: powershell, dll, .net-assembly, 7zip

I am trying to load an assembly using this:

```
$pathToDll = "C:\zip\SevenZipSharp.dll"
$pathTo7zDll = "C:\zip\7z.dll"
$dllByteArray= [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($pathToDll)
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($dllByteArray)
```

This doesn't throw an exception however when I want to use the library `SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor` like this:

```
[SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor]::SetLibraryPath($pathTo7zDll)
```

It says: `Exception calling "SetLibraryPath" with "1" argument(s): "The type initializer for 'SevenZip.SevenZipLibraryManager' threw an exception."`

However if I replace `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($dllByteArray)` with

```
Add-Type -path $pathToDll
```

it works fine.

Why does it throw the Exception if I load the assembly from the Byte array?

**EDIT:**
The reason I want to load it using a Byte array is because if I use `Add-Type` it seems to keep a handle on the .dll and I can't delete it using `Remove-Item` later on.

**EDIT:** This worked:

```
[System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager]::AppSettings["7zLocation"] = $pathToDll
```

That needs to be called before calling `[SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor]::SetLibraryPath($pathTo7zDll)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library is using Reflection to find its own path via `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` and initializing some static fields with this value. [See the source code](https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SevenZip/LibraryManager.cs):

```
private static string _libraryFileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["7zLocation"] ??
        Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "7z.dll");
```

However, if you load an assembly directly from a byte array, the Location is null and GetDirectoryName will throw an exception. It isn't a limitation of PowerShell, it's a problem with the library.

There may be a possible work around, which would be to load System.Configuration and set the 7zLocation app setting before trying to load the library.

Since the library seems to be trying to let you set the path via `SetLibraryPath`, this is probably a bug and should be reported to the maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are running into a fundamental limitation of .NET.  Once an assembly is loaded into your app domain, there is no unloading that dll.  Do you need to use a type from the assembly or just reflect over it?  If it is the latter, you can load the DLL into a [reflection-only context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172331(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: But why is it throwing an Exception when I call [SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor]::SetLibraryPath($pathTo7zDll)?

Comment: My guess is that the assembly being loaded depends on another assembly that can't be found.  Try to load the missing assembly first.  You need to dig into the details of that exception - look for its InnerException and examine it - recursively until InnerException is null.